# How to group with a written specified DataContextClass?

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, var

I want to group dvdlist by categoryid, Similar to this, but no DVDDataContext 
This one works,

```
DvdDataContext db = new DvdDataContext();
var q = from b in db.DvdLists
        group b by b.CategoryId into g
        select new { CategoryID = g.Key, DvdLists = g };
```

I need the following kind of code, but the error occurs at GetTable()=g

```
DataContext db = new DataContext(conString);
var dvd = db.GetTable<DvdList>();
var query = from b in dvd
            group b by b.CategoryId into g
            select new { CategoryId = g.Key, GetTable<DvdList>()= g };
```

Comment: You're trying to assign a value *to a method*. It's not at all clear what you expect that to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify GetTable() in anonymous types. Try  { CategoryId = g.Key, GetTable= g };

Hope it helps!